# Advanced mysql queries, fetching from several tables and rows at once. Joins?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a project where I have information stored in several tables that all connect to each other. I believe that the table and column format is logical and the best choice. The problem though, is that I don't have enough knowledge to build queries advanced enough to fetch all the information I need.

The main table is ab_ads, where advertisements are stored. These ads can be assigned several formats (ie. 250x360, 980x120 etc), and you can also select the region where they should be showing (ie. Skåne, Stockholm, Kalmar, Dalarna, Jämtland etc).

This is how I store my data. I'm not showing all tables but I hope this is sufficient.

**Advertisements column (ab_ads):** (There are more columns but they are not relevant)

```
ID    orgnum         company_name   title           content         link
1     556664-7524    Company Inc    Lorem ipsum     Lorem ipsum     URL
```

**Advertisement states (ab_ads_states):**

```
ID    adID    stateID
1     1       2             // Skåne
2     1       5             // Kalmar
3     1       8             // Stockholm
4     1       10            // Värmland
5     2       2             // Skåne
6     2       5             // Kalmar
7     3       8             // Stockholm
8     4       10            // Värmland
```

**Advertisement formats (ab_ads_formats)**

```
ID    adID    formatID
1     1       1             // 250x360
2     1       2             // 980x120
3     2       1             // 250x360
4     3       2             // 980x120
```

**Formats table (ab_formats)**

```
ID    name        width    height
1     Format 1    250      360
2     Format 2    980      120
```

So, I have two flash banners both are supposed to call a PHP-script which in turn is supposed to deliver an XML-file back with all the results.

I know how to select data from different tables, but I've never worked with selecting multiple rows from another table and merging them into one, which I suppose is that I need to do here. I'm very thankful for any help I can get.

The flash banners will send two parameters to the PHP file, `stateID` and `formatID`. Which means I have to `SELECT ad WHERE state = param AND format = format`. But since I store multiple entries for the ad states I don't know how to do it.

**EDIT:** 
I would also like to fetch the format names in the query and get them in the following format: "Format 1,Format 2" in a column named "formats". I guess this would require some kind of join?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
select ab.name as formats, aa.* from ab_ads as aa
inner join ab_ads_states as aas on aa.id = aas.adid and aas.stateId = stateIdParam
inner join ab_ads_formats as aaf on aa.id = aaf.adid and aaf.formatId = formatIdParam
inner join ab_formats as ab on aaf.formatid = ab.id
```

Edit:
I'm not very good with mySql, and don't have anything to test this on, but I think [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) may be what you are looking for.  If so, it will probably look something like this:

```
select group_concat(ab.name separator ", ") as formats from ab_ads aa
inner join ab_ads_states as aas on aa.id = aas.adid and aas.stateId = 2
inner join ab_ads_formats as aaf on aa.id = aaf.adid and aaf.formatId in(1,2)
inner join ab_formats as ab on aaf.formatid = ab.id
group by ab.id
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I changed "aaf.formatId = formatIdParam" into "aaf.formatId IN (1,2)" to try it out. Although, I noticed that if the ad has both of those formats assigned I get two rows. Is there any way to merge the columns on the two rows, etc (Format1, Format2) into one row where the column "formats" has a string like this: "Format 1, Format 2"?

Comment: @Jonathan That is a more complex query, called a pivot.  Is there a maximum number of formats that could be returned? Or do you need it to return a list of all the formats where there could be "format 1, format 2,......format X"?

Comment: preferably the later option because the formats might increase over time. But it depends if it's possible or not. Thanks for taking your time to help me! :)

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! I'll mess around with it this weekend and see if I can get that working as well. You've been very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below SQL:

```
SELECT count(aaf.ID) AS TotalFormat,
   group_concat(ab.name) AS formats
FROM ab_ads aa
INNER JOIN ab_ads_states AS aas ON aa.ID = aas.adID
AND aas.stateID = 2
INNER JOIN ab_ads_formats AS aaf ON aa.id = aaf.adID
AND aaf.formatID in(1,2)
INNER JOIN ab_formats AS ab ON aaf.formatID = ab.ID
GROUP BY aaf.adID HAVING TotalFormat >=2
```

## SQL Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f0ab/10